# Strange css bug in Polymer 2 with paper-menu-button

Tags: css, z-index, polymer-2.x

When my menu button expands downward, something with the z-index or opacity gets messed up. Notice how the menu options appear to have a transparent background.

[image]

However, when the menu expands upward, it looks great and can be used without problems.

[image]

My custom element imports some styles...

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/default-theme.html">
```

I have tried to adjust the z-index and opacity with no success.

```
        paper-listbox paper-item {
            z-index: 9;
            opacity: inherit;
        }

        paper-menu-button paper-icon-button {
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: unset;
        }
```

Here is the markup for the paper-menu-button...

```
    <iron-list items="[[collection]]" as="item">
        <template>
            <paper-item>[[item.title_name]]
                <paper-menu-button horizontal-align="right" dynamic-align="false" class="forceRight">
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" alt="menu"
                                       role="button"></paper-icon-button>
                    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" role="listbox">
                        <paper-item role="option">songs</paper-item>
                        <paper-item role="option">settings</paper-item>
                        <paper-item role="option">details</paper-item>
                    </paper-listbox>
                </paper-menu-button>
            </paper-item>
        </template>
      </iron-list>
```

I cannot even begin to imagine why the menu options would look good expanding upward but look bad expanding downward.  I tried to create a jsbin but failed.  So I created a tiny project to replicate the css bug.  You can clone the repo here ...

https://github.com/bwfrieds/css-is-hard

Update:  I attempted to use IronOverlayBehavior but failed.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/issues/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is caused by how [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) works. In this particular example, each element in the `<iron-list>` has `will-change` and `transform` css properties setup, which create a new stacking context: this traps the `paper-menu-button` (and its internal `iron-dropdown`) within it.

I'd suggest to set `z-index` on the `<paper-item>` while the menu is opened:

```
<paper-menu-button dynamic-align="false" on-opened-changed="_setZindex">

//...

_setZindex(event) {
  // The <paper-menu-button>
  const menu = event.target;
  // The <paper-item>
  const item = menu.parentNode;
  item.style.zIndex = menu.opened ? 101 : null;
}
```

Comment: This is a cool solution to something a lot of people run into with the `iron-list` component!

Another way to go, particularly being it looks like they all have the same content (though it wouldn't be a blocker either way) and may also have some performance benefits, would be to use a single `paper-listbox` component outside of the `iron-list` that was placed and attributed in response to an event triggered by clicking on the `paper-icon-button`. Give your app less nodes to track, while possibly keeping those settings options closer to the working parts of your app.